# What is the correct way of setting the Action attribute in a Django form

Tags: django

I have an html form in a Django system and I cannot find the correct way to implement the Action attribute in the form

**html**

```
<form action="stages" method="post">
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('<str:partner_pk>/stages/', views.Stages.as_view(), name="stages"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class Stages(View):
    """CBV for setting stages."""
    url = 'duo/stages.html'

    def get(self, request, partner_pk):
        app.context['partner_pk'] = partner_pk
        return render(request, self.url, app.context)

    def post(self, request, partner_pk):
        """Render the POST request."""
        stages_selected = app.update_stages(request)
        if app.context['use_stages'] and not stages_selected:
            messages.error(request, 'You have not selected any stages.')
            return render(request, f'{partner_pk}', app.context)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(f'duo/{partner_pk}/'))
```

The error I get on clicking submit is:

```
RuntimeError at /duo/2/stages/stages
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set...
```

I have tried various other urls in *action* but the all give an error message

[EDIT 200200828]
The APPEND_SLASH message is misleading. It is just the message that I get with the html

```
<form action="stages" method="post">
```

If I change the html to

```
<form action={% url 'stages' partner_pk %} method="post">
```

or

```
<form action='?' method="post">
```

I get the message

> NoReverseMatch at /duo/2/stages/'

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set APPEND_SLASH option so all of your routes should have / afterwards but still it wouldn't work as you are appending relative path (notice stages doubling in URL)

Considering you are posting on same route you could  omit  action attribute

```
<form   method="post">
```

or use something like (as HTML5 standard does not allow empty action)

```
<form  action='?' method="post">
```

additionally you could use full path something like this

```
<form action="{% url 'stages' partner_pk %}"  method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks. But all of these solution s give the error `NoReverseMatch at /duo/2/stages/`

Comment: you need to check this setting https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#append-slash

Comment: Thank you, but that does not seem to be relevant - see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case was the *reverse(url)*

I change the *post* method in **views.py** to

```
def post(self, request, partner_pk):
    """Render the POST request."""
    stages_selected = app.update_stages(request)
    if app.context['use_stages'] and not stages_selected:
        messages.error(request, 'You have not selected any stages.')
        return render(request, f'{partner_pk}', app.context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/duo/{partner_pk}')
```

and it works